# Type id of std::string for variable vs. string in argument?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-literals

I referred to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid to write code which does different things for different types.

The code is as below and the explanation is given in the comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void test_template(const T &t)
{
    if (typeid(t) == typeid(double))
        cout <<"double\n";
    if (typeid(t) == typeid(string))
        cout <<"string\n";
    if (typeid(t) == typeid(int))
        cout <<"int\n";
}

int main()
{
    auto a = -1;
    string str = "ok";
    test_template(a); // Prints int
    test_template("Helloworld"); // Does not print string
    test_template(str); // Prints string
    test_template(10.00); // Prints double

    return 0;
}
```

Why does `test_template(str)` print "string" whereas `test_template("Helloworld")` does not?

BTW, my g++ version is g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Sure, it's at a basic level, but the question is complete, clear, and OP even includes a compiler version!

Comment: `"Helloworld"` is not a `std::string`. But `"Helloworld"s` would be.

Comment: @TartanLlama: I would guess it's because of a user wanting to use `typeid` to write horribly fragile code.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a thing that site advises. `typeid` is handy for debugging/testing assumptions of complex, template code in my experience; & presumably some non-debugging polymorphic situation that I've thankfully never needed. If you don't need the latter, it's not a replacement for overloading. One of these is fully standard & predictable; the other is a brittle implementation-defined mapping of types to usually unhelpful codes. Using templates with `typeid` will produce _at best_ code that is no more efficient, but much less bearable to read, than using normal functions & overloading them.

Comment: ...and if, after all that, you do find yourself needing to branch based on the `typeid` of a polymorphic object at runtime, then I _think_ the accepted wisdom is that it probably indicates a flaw in the design.

Comment: @TartanLlama Downvoting isn't going to teach anybody how to program better. Well written answers, on the other hand, will :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this call

```
test_template("Helloworld"); // Does not print string
```

the argument `"Helloworld"` is a string literal that has type `const char[11]`.

Because the function parameter is a referenced type

```
void test_template(const T &t) 
                          ^^^
```

then within the function the argument (more precisely the parameter) has the type `const char ( &t )[11]`.

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays with the number of elements equal to the number of characters in string literal plus the terminating zero.

In this call

```
test_template(str);
```

the argument has type `std::string` because the variable `str` is declared like

```
string str = "ok";
^^^^^^
```

It was initialized by the string literal `"ok"` nevertheless the object itself is of the type `std::string`.

Comment: Should `conat char` be `const char`? (I can't submit an edit with just one change.)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe What do you mean?

Comment: Well, `conat` in `conat char ( &t )[11]` in your answer.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Redundant const qualifiers are considered like one const qualifier. The reference themselves can not be const. It is objects that they refer can be considered like constant objects.

Comment: I mean [const](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_(computer_programming)) is a type qualifier. But what is `conat`? A typo or something else?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Oh, I am sorry. It is a typo.:)

Comment: Perhaps mention that if OP had passed `"Helloworld"s` rather than `"Helloworld"`, it would have constructed a `std::string` and behaved as OP expected.

Answer (score 16):

String literals in C++ are of type `const char[N+1]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the string. `std::string` is a standard library class which owns a string and provides a number of operations over it. A `std::string` can be constructed from a `const char[N]`, but they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 10):

String literals like `"Helloworld"` are constants arrays of characters.

The `std::string` class have a constructor that can take pointers to string literals, but a string literal is in itself not a `std::string` object.

---

As a side-note, using a function like your is considered a code-smell and bad design. Use overloaded functions taking different arguments instead. That will also solve your problem with the strings.

Comment: Agreed, there's no point in having a template at all here. There's no common functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I will consider using overloaded functions instead.